# Getting 1042 error while connecting to MySql database via SSH on remote desktop

Tags: c#, mysql, ssh

I can't get connected to MySql database via SSH on remote desktop. I use C# and SshNet library. Actually, I have no problem to connect to the database with the help of popular tools, such as SQL Manager Lite, but when I do the same thing with the same settings with my tool - always get

> Mysql 1042 Error (Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts)

Also, the part in my.cnf is edited to 
    `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` and
    `# skip-networking`. (Yes I tried with localhost and server ip on bind-address - same problem)

And I also granted all permissions to the user. Double-checked that.

Please, look at the code, maybe I missed something.

And sorry, I'm using forms, I just will need GUI :{

Many thanks in advance, everybody.

```cs
PasswordConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new PasswordConnectionInfo("serverip", "sshlogin", "sshpass");
        connectionInfo.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        using (var client = new SshClient(connectionInfo))
        {
            try
            {
                client.Connect();
                if (client.IsConnected)
                {
                    label1.Text = "ssh ok";
                }
                else
                {
                    label1.Text = "ssh shit";
                }

                var port = new ForwardedPortRemote(3306, "serverip", 3306);
                client.AddForwardedPort(port);
                port.Start();
                if (port.IsStarted)
                {
                    label5.Text = "port open";
                }
                else
                {
                    label5.Text = "port shit";
                }
                var conn_info = "Server=serverip;Port=3306;Database=database;Uid=remoteuser;Pwd=password;";
                bool isConn = false;
                MySqlConnection conn = null;
                try
                {
                    conn = new MySqlConnection(conn_info);
                    conn.Open();
                    isConn = true;
                }
                catch (ArgumentException a_ex)
                {

                    label3.Text = "Check the Connection String.";
                    label4.Text = a_ex.Message;
                    label5.Text = a_ex.ToString();

                }
                catch (MySqlException ex)
                {
                    string sqlErrorMessage = "Message: " + ex.Message + "\n" +
                    "Source: " + ex.Source + "\n" +
                    "Number: " + ex.Number;
                    label3.Text = sqlErrorMessage;

                    isConn = false;
                    switch (ex.Number)
                    {
                       case 1042: // Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts (Check Server,Port)
                            break;
                        case 0: // Access denied 
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
                client.Disconnect();
                label2.Text = isConn.ToString();
            }
            catch (SocketException exd)
            {
                label5.Text = exd.Message;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Exception?

Comment: have you tried a google search.. if not check out this article http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: To Ron Beyer: I catch exception, it is MySQL 1042 error. To Methodman: Yes particulary this one, and many many others. And I googled, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are using `var port = new ForwardedPortRemote(3306, "serverip", 3306);` which will forward connections to port 3306 on the *remote* machine to 3306 on the *local* machine.  Is this what you're trying to do?  It seems like you want `ForwardPortLocal` or whatever the function would be called to forward connections the other direction.

Comment: Hi, I am not too good with SSH so I just tried all possible variants here: `var port = new ForwardedPortLocal(3306, "serverip", 3306);` `var port = new ForwardedPortLocal(0, "serverip", 3306);` `var port = new ForwardedPortLocal("localhost", 0, "serverip", 3306);` `var port = new ForwardedPortLocal("localhost", 3306, "serverip", 3306);`  And the same with `ForwardedPortRemote`.

Comment: @aquatko there may be some confusion as to where you should use `serverip` and where you should use `localhost`.  Assuming you're running the code on `localhost` and you're trying to connect to a MySQL on `serverip`, you actually want to do (in psuedocode):

`ssh to serverip`, then
`ForwardPortLocal(3306, "localhost", 3306)`, and finally
`mysql_connect("localhost:3306")`

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. I tried what you proposed with `localhost`, it didn't worked, but somehow get worked with `127.0.0.1`. Good luck to you.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue. The MySql database was running on ubuntu and required SSH connection to connect. I downloaded the sshnet .NET 4.0 library from [here](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/120565). Then, importing the library into the project, the following steps were followed:

1. Establishing the ssh connection

   `var client = new SshClient("ip address of linux server", "username", "password"); client.Connect();`
2. Check if the client got connected. If yes, then the port forwarding was done from Linux server to local server. This was a kind of magical line.

   `var portForwardedL = new ForwardedPortLocal(3306, "127.0.0.3", 3306);
    client.AddForwardedPort(portForwardedL);
    portForwardedL.Start();`
3. Now just connect with the MySql Database using the forwarded serverip and port

   ```
         using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=127.0.0.3;PORT=3306;UID=username;PWD=password;DATABASE=database_name"))
               {
                   using (MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM cities", con))
                   {
                       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                       MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(com);
                       da.Fill(ds);
                       foreach (DataRow drow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                       {
                           Console.WriteLine("From MySql: " + drow[1].ToString());
                       }
                   }
               }
   ```

That's it! It worked like a magic!!!  Please be sure to close the ssh connection.